# Big performance difference reading shapefiles between QGIS and R

Tags: qgis, shapefile, r, performance

I'm trying to read the belgian landuse ESRI shapefile from geofabrik.de:

http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/belgium.html

In QGIS it's just a matter of seconds, but in R using the readOGR function my RAM (4gbs) fills and the reading process does not actually end even after several minutes.

I on a lenovo i5-4300 intel quadcore laptop with windows 7 on it and I use R studio Version 0.99.447 and R x64 3.2.1.

The code is the following:

```
shp.landuse <- readOGR(layer="landuse")
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: 4Gb of RAM isn't much -- Windows 7 uses 3Gb before I get to the desktop. Windows and Linux both cache file I/O when RAM isn't used for anything else, so the behavior you're describing isn't a major concern. Please **edit the question** to provide more details on your operating system, the actual file sizes of the shapefile triple, and the exact timing involved as R imports the file into something it can use (which involves reading the .dbf, which drawing in QGIS doesn't)

Comment: QGIS is dedicated GIS software, I would expect it to handle loading shape files better than R. However, as Vince says: you need to give more information including the R script you're using to load your data.

Comment: I was [reading](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html) lately that R holds all objects in virtual memory which has limitations. So maybe a better way would be to use something that handles memory better - This is just an opinion as I am just learning R

Comment: Is creating a database an option? if so how to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this data? What are the analysis or display steps you are looking to do?

Comment: So basically I have a number of shapefiles (it would be handy if I could combine them). This data will first be filtered to have a "final" dataset" this final dataset will be used in shiny. When choosing a location on a map, the user will see appear data points that are for example in a 4 km radius, so this mean that the "final" dataset will be queried and filtered live on shiny

Answer (score 3):

There's a better library for reading really large shapefiles - fastshp. Doesn't seem to be available in repositories but the .tgz binaries are [here](http://www.rforge.net/fastshp/files/). Here are the results for rgdal and fastshp with a 130MB shapefile with 32,545 features:

```
library(fastshp)
library(rgdal)

system.time(
  test.fastshp <- read.shp("tz-landcover-ge.shp")
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 1.570   0.135   1.732 

system.time(
  test.rgdal <- readOGR(layer="tz-landcover-ge")
)
# OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
# Source: "/Users/simbamangu/Downloads/tz-landcover-ge/", layer: "tz-landcover-ge"
# with 32545 features
# It has 9 fields
# user  system elapsed 
# 11.216   0.799  12.063
```

7 times faster - would have been 178 times faster (0.063 sec) if I hadn't asked it to use format="polygons".

However, it provides a different class of object - a 'shp' instead of 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', which is a list of other objects (lines / polygon definitions depending on 'format' - doesn't work with points).

Comment: Hello, is it possible to merge different shapefiles in that format? Also is it possible to plot and subset these shapefiles?

Comment: I never really understood the point of the fastshp package. So, it is fast. It does not produce a standard spatial object class so, you still have the overhead of coercing to a class you can work with. This is very likely why it is depreciated. I would also note that it is not good practice to aim novice users to depreciated packages. Because of changes to both R and library dependencies, it often ends up creating more headaches for the user and could yield outright incorrect results.

Comment: Agreed. As per OP's final comment, fastshp might provide a way to 'filter' a large set and then coerce or work with a subset (unclear what exactly they wanted to do). I personally now would usually convert to PostGIS / Spatialite and readOGR from the db instead of a shapefile. Any suggestions from your side, perhaps a better answer? ;)